# Is it bad practice to expose a function which creates table on live production database

Tags: database

We have a module which analyzes csv files and stores the data to database.In order to map the csv data to correct fields, the mapping information was stored in a table.And we create a html page to import the mapping data if someone needs to deal with some csv files with different format.
However, someone told me this is very dangerous as it would create a new table during the import.So is it bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad practice compared to what ? This sounds like pretty common practice in fact.

Creating a table requires elevated access. So if someone finds how to inject queries via input data, the injected query will have table generation level access.

- csv file handling scripts has to filter carefully against unwanted
  data.
- Table creation scripts should use restricted DB user while
  connecting to DB. Not root.

Other than these 2 precautions can prevent, i do not see any bad practice or any dangerous approach.

Comment: He said create new table on live production database is bad practice as it is very dangerous

Comment: @Max Do you mean you want to change tables while tables are being used actively ?

Comment: No, just create a new table

Comment: I do not think it is very dangerous.
Does users upload csv files?